# Error using conditional values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am trying to use the following code to set a new column, `wdf['Thunder']` to the  value of `wdf['RngT]` if the word `Thunderstorm` is in the column `wdf['Notes']`. However, I keep getting the error `TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable`.  None of the columns are floats. RngT is an int, Notes is an object.  Full code is:

```
wdf['Thunder'] = [wdf['RngT'] if 'Thunderstorm' in x else 0 for x in wdf['Notes']]
```

New to pandas, so would appreciate any insight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider a performant alternative, `np.where`:

```
wdf['Thunder'] = np.where(
    wdf['Notes'].astype(str).str.contains('Thunderstorm'), wdf['RngT'], 0
)
```

Note that your first approach probably didn't work because your column was mixing strings and floats. Using `astype(str)` before checking for containment should fix that.